# GUI: configure the racket:text% to read-only

Tags: racket

I want to use an editor to display a log from a program, I just need a very basic text field:

- With a vertical scrollbar
- With a contextual menu for copy/paste
- Prevent the user from changing the text

In order to activate the copy/paste menu, I use the class racket:text% from framework rather than the basic one.

How to prevent the user from changing the text?

I read the documentation, as far as I understand the closest thing I found is lock method:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/editor___.html?q=lock#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._editor~3c~25~3e%29._lock%29%29

But it is not convenient, as it also prevent my program to write the data.
I also find get-read-write? but cannot find set-read-write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lock` method, and just unlock the editor around any modifications that you want to do. You may find it useful to write a `call-with-unlock` helper function or `with-unlock` macro.

If you do your updates from the eventspace's handler thread (and you probably should; use `queue-callback` if they originate from another thread), then as long as you re-lock the editor at the end of an update, the user will never be able to interact with the unlocked editor.

Comment: so, no risk for the user to accidentally insert data while the editor is unlocked?

Comment: Right. User interaction happens through events that are handled by code running in the eventspace's handler thread. That thread can only do one thing at a time, so if it's busy running your code, then user events get queued up until the handler thread is free. So if your code locks the editor before returning, it will be locked when the handler thread processes the queued user events.